# TPL control flow issue

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have three classes:

`BargeGrouper` class which implements `IBargeGrouper` and has `Group(IEnumerable<Barge> ungrouped)` method.

`BargeGroupMap` class which implements `IBargeGroupShow` and has `Show(IEnumerable<BargeGroup>` method.

And the class where I call both if these into: `GroupingModule` and it's `Run()`.

Problem is that when I call `Group(ungrouped);` and then want to `Show(bargeGroups);` I got `IndexOutOfRange`exception in `Show(bargeGroups);` because the`IEnumerable` I pass to it as a parameter has `Count` property many more than actual elements in it. I found out that grouped collection is being returned as empty from `Group` most of the time despite I use `ContinueWith` to fill that collection with `BargeGroup` elements.

`Group` method of `BargeGrouper`

```
public IEnumerable<BargeGroup> Group(IEnumerable<Barge> ungroupedBarges)
{
    List<BargeGroup> bargeGroups = new List<BargeGroup>();
    Int32 groupNumber = 0;

    var riverBarges = from barge in ungroupedBarges
                      where barge != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Intern(barge.River))
                      let river = String.Intern(barge.River)
                      orderby river, barge.MileMarker ascending
                      group barge by river into barges
                      select barges.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (IEnumerable<Barge> barges in riverBarges)
    {
        Task.Run(() => ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber)).ContinueWith(t=>
        {
            IEnumerable<BargeGroup> riverGroups = t.Result;
            bargeGroups.AddRange(riverGroups);
        });
    }

    return bargeGroups;
}
```

`ShowBargeGroups`:

```
public void ShowBargeGroups(IEnumerable<BargeGroup> bargeGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Barge groups :");
    if (bargeGroups != null)
    {
        foreach (var group in bargeGroups.Where(b => b != null))
        {
            var title = String.Format("{0}\n\t | {1} \t\t | {2} \t | {3} \t|", group.Id, "Id", "River", "MileMarker");
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            foreach (var barge in group.Barges)
            {
                var caption = String.Format("\t | {0}\t | {1} \t | {2} \t|", barge.Id, barge.River, barge.MileMarker);
                Console.WriteLine(caption);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And usage in `GroupingModule`:.

`var groupBarges = bargeGrouper.Group(barges);`

`bargeGroupShow.ShowBargeGroups(groupBarges);`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Show us `ShowBargeGroups`. Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov please, see update. I use .net 4.5. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When using `Task.Run`, which returns a `Task` without asynchronously waiting on it, execution of the next line will happen immediately, it won't wait for the delegate passed to complete.

One way of resolving this would be to issue the calls to `ResolveRiver` in parallel and asynchronously wait for multiple tasks to complete:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<BargeGroup>> GroupAsync(IEnumerable<Barge> ungroupedBarges)
{
    // Do the grouping

    var riverTasks = riverBarges.Select(barges => 
                                        Task.Run(ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber)));

    var result = await Task.WhenAll(riverTasks);
    bargeGroups.AddRange(result.Result.SelectMany(x => x));
    return bargeGroups;
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    var barges = await GroupAsync(ungroupedBarges);
    ShowBargeGroups(barges);
}
```

Note I'd be careful with the `ref` parameter being passed and called in parallel, that won't be safe. If you can remove the `groupNumber` from the equation, do so.

Comment: Would riverTasks have a Result property?

Comment: @Sega No, It wouldn't. I've modified the code, thank you for that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Task.Run doesn't do it's job immediately. So at least you've got a race condition in your code. Try it like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BargeGroup>> Group(IEnumerable<Barge> ungroupedBarges)
{
    List<BargeGroup> bargeGroups = new List<BargeGroup>();
    Int32 groupNumber = 0;

    var riverBarges = from barge in ungroupedBarges
                      where barge != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Intern(barge.River))
                      let river = String.Intern(barge.River)
                      orderby river, barge.MileMarker ascending
                      group barge by river into barges
                      select barges.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (IEnumerable<Barge> barges in riverBarges)
    {
        var riverGroups = await Task.Run(() => ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber));
        bargeGroups.AddRange(riverGroups);
    }

    return bargeGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that by the time you return from the `Group` method the `Task` is done processing the `bargeGroups` list. I suspect that your `ResolveRiver` method might take some time.

You need to wait for the task doing the processing to end before returning the enumerable from `Group`. I'd suggest making `Group` **async** and *awaiting* for the `Task`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BargeGroup>> Group(IEnumerable<Barge> ungroupedBarges)
{
    List<BargeGroup> bargeGroups = new List<BargeGroup>();
    Int32 groupNumber = 0;

    var riverBarges = from barge in ungroupedBarges
                      where barge != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Intern(barge.River))
                      let river = String.Intern(barge.River)
                      orderby river, barge.MileMarker ascending
                      group barge by river into barges
                      select barges.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (IEnumerable<Barge> barges in riverBarges)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber)).ContinueWith(t=>
        {
            IEnumerable<BargeGroup> riverGroups = t.Result;
            bargeGroups.AddRange(riverGroups);
        });
    }

    return bargeGroups;
}
```

Indeed, the proper way to go would be to make `ResolveRiver` async and await it. Then you could get rid of the `bargeGroups` `List` that you are using to communicate with the `Task`.

If you don't want to go the *async/await* way you may just `.Wait()` the `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

Task.Run in your code creates another awaitable which is most likely going to be executed after your function returns. The easiest solution would be to wait for it with the Wait function.

```
Task.Run(() => ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber)).ContinueWith(t=>
    {
        IEnumerable<BargeGroup> riverGroups = t.Result;
        bargeGroups.AddRange(riverGroups);
    }).Wait()
```

or event better, you do not need the Task.Run, just waiting for the continuation function would be enough:

```
ResolveRiver(barges, ref groupNumber)).ContinueWith(t=>
    {
        IEnumerable<BargeGroup> riverGroups = t.Result;
        bargeGroups.AddRange(riverGroups);
    }).Wait();
```